# Previous evaluation has not completed error while using send_keys Internet Explorer

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium

I'm using Python 2.7 and selenium is 3.4.3:

```
search_field= self.driver.find_element(By.ID ,'Searchbox')  
time.sleep(10)
search_field.send_keys('test' + Keys.RETURN)
```

It works in Chrome & Firefox, but it does not work in IE when I use :

```
search_field.send_keys('test' + Keys.RETURN)
```

It will return error as :

```
previous evaluation has not completed.
```

How to make send_keys to work?

Add Html

```
<div>
<input type="text" value="" id="Searchbox" name="name" class="input-xlarge search-query searchInput" style="padding:3px;" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.1">
<span class="btn btn-small btn-warning" style="border-radius:0px;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;height:28px;margin-left:1px;" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.2"><i class="icon-search icon-on-right bigger-110" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0.1.0.0.1.0.0.2.0"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: So, you don't have a search button?

Comment: Yes I have, But now I just cant input the text on Searchbox

Comment: Add please your HTML.

Comment: @RatmirAsanov added

Comment: Did you try my answer? How is going?

Comment: @RatmirAsanov it's not work

Comment: Any error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code for your case:

```
search_field = self.driver.find_element(By.ID ,'Searchbox')
time.sleep(10)
search_field.send_keys('test')

search_button = self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn.btn-small.btn-warning')
time.sleep(10)
search_button.click()
```

Hope it helps you!

PS: BTW, you can use explicit or implicit waits instead of `time.sleep(10)`.

Comment: this is work I need more wait time for random elements

Comment: @ZivHus, If my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please.

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all :

```
previous evaluation has not completed
```

A simple solution would be to break down the compound statement in multiple statements as follows :

```
search_field.send_keys("test")
search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

---

### Update :

As per the `HTML` you have updated within the question, to `send_keys` within the `<input>` tag you can use either of the following line of code :

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,"//input[@id='Searchbox']").send_keys("test")
#or
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,"//input[@name='name']").send_keys("test") 
#or
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH ,"//input[@class='input-xlarge search-query searchInput' and @id='Searchbox']").send_keys("test")
```

Comment: I have tried just search_field.send_keys("test"), but it's same of error message

Comment: Update the question with your Code trial, relevant `HTML` and `Error Stack Trace`.

Comment: I have been added the HTML, I don't have more error message

Comment: `it's same no work` doesn't throws any light on whats happening. Update the question with your current code and error stack trace.

Comment: It's fixed, I waiting more time for random elements